# layout is not recognised by eclipse

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i almost face the same problem again. Few minutes ago i posted a question concerning that, the

```
R.layout.mylayout
```

is not recognised by eclipse despite that, the layout folder contains my xml file and the layout folder is located inside the res folder. the answer was to delete the R.java from the gen folder and clean the project and restart the workspace.

Now, i face the same problem again despite that i followed the previous steps to solve the error but the error which is that, the

```
R.layout.mylayout
```

is not recognise still exist and there is also exclaimation mark beside the project name.

is there any other ways to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

**Project - > Clean**

Select "**Build Automatically**" so that every time you clean the project, it will be rebuilt. And yeah, make sure you are saving the file before cleaning it (I know it is weird but sometimes the errors refuse to go away until you save it and then Clean it). Make sure that there is **no error** in the files in the **layout folder**, as it sometimes prevents the auto-generation of the code in R.java

Also, make sure that your code in MainActivity.java **does not have**  **`import android.R`**. Eclipse tends to add that when you are managing the imports.

Comment: i followed the steps u posted but nothing changed

Comment: Did you try cleaning it after removing android.R ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check you `import` statements.... If **you have by mistake imported the** `android.R` , then **please remove it at once**.... and then **clean the project** and see how it works...

Comment: i removed the imported android.R and cleaned the project and the error was saying that R cant be resolved as variable.Hence, i imported android.R again and the problem still there

Comment: @ Neverever import android.R in your Android project.... else you won't be able to access any of your projects resources.... Now try this... REMOVE THE android.R from your Project... Scan every bit of your xml, your java.... error must be located there

Comment: Remove android.R from imports.Clean the project.Rebuild. If it still shows that R is not resolved, then place an import statement like 'import my.package.name.R' where 'my.package.name' is your package name. Then rebuild the project.

Comment: without importing amdroid.R, eclipse underline R. with red line wich means there is a mistake and suggest to import android.R

Comment: **DO NOT IMPORT android.R AT ANY COST**

Answer (score 0):

Run the Lint tool. Right click your project and check under Android tools. check what is the issue using that.